# Visual Studio communication with SQL Server - Server Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm having trouble with Visual Studio connecting with SQL Server...

From this code:

```
public ActionResult SearchByRestaurant()
{
    User objUser = new User();

    if (Session["UserId"] != null)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);
        objUser = objContext.ContextUser.Find(id);
    }

    objUser.SearchResult = new List<SearchResult>();
    objUser.PreferencesList = objContext.ContextPreferences.Where(s => s.Status == 1).ToList()
    objUser.RestaurantListAll = objContext.ContextRestaurant.Where(s => s.Status == 1).ToList();

    if (objUser.SelectedPreferences == null)
        objUser.SelectedPreferences = new int[] { };

    return View(objUser);
}
```

I'm getting an exception for this line:

```
objUser.PreferencesList = objContext.ContextPreferences.Where(s => s.Status == 1).ToList()
```

Exception:

> 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Login failed for user 'sa'.

I've tried going into the settings to add the 'sa' user as a connection but it isn't working.

Further details:

- Working with Visual Studio ASP .Net Framwork
- Writing in C#
- Using a basic SQL Server database that is already setup in VS

I really appreciate any help that can be given, and if you're willing enough to help me further please message me. Thank you!

**Update:**

I tried enabling the 'sa' account, and am now receiving this error:

> 'System.InvalidOperationException' in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.

Comment: Can you show the connection string in your web.config?

Comment: Error is so obvious, show us connection string

Comment: <configSections> <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" /> </configSections> <connectionStrings> <add name="ContextClass" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Persist Security Info=True;database=db_FoodAllergy;User ID=sa;Password=saa" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> </connectionStrings>